# Git branch indicator in GitHub's Atom Editor

Tags: git, atom-editor

Is there a feature/package to indicate in Atom which branch you are currently working on. The editor seems to flawlessly swap between them but it'd be nice if I had a visual cue to remind me that the code I'm touching is on THIS branch not THAT branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Branch indicator is in bottom right 
[image: Bottom right is branch indicator]

For managing git from Atom i use [Git Plus](https://atom.io/packages/git-plus). It offers add, commit, push, pull, rebase, merge, diff, log.